# Singly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++

I have source code that adds items to linked list and prints them.
Now the "print()" function prints items from end to first. There are 2 questions:
1. is "99" the first item in linked list ?
2. if "11" is the first item in linked list, how i can set the start position of the list to print from first ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
};

Node *head = NULL;
int *start = &head->data; // Get start of linked list

void insert(int data)
{
    Node *new_node = new Node();
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = head;
    head = new_node;
}

void display()
{
    Node *ptr;
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout<< ptr->data << " ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 11; i <= 100; i += 10)
        insert(i);
    cout<< "Setting head->data address...";
    &head->data = start;
    cout<< "[ OK ]\n";
    cout<< "The linked list is: ";
    display();
    cout<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Node *head = NULL; int *start = &head->data;` does this not immediately break everything?

Comment: And even if it works, `99` will never be in the linked list, since `99 - 11 = 88` which is not a multiply of 10.

Comment: actually ```int *start = &head->data;``` break every thing.  I'm trying to assign first of list to it but i can't. @scohe001
After all this doesn't matter 99 it not multiply of 10

Comment: `Node *head = NULL; int *start = &head->data; // Get start of linked list` -- Those two lines are outside of `main`, meaning they are executed before `main` begins.  Thus the error should be obvious, given that information.  What were your intentions of writing code outside of `main` like that?

Comment: Yes @ali, because `head` is NULL. So `head->data` or without the syntactic sugar, `(*head).data` is attempting to dereference NULL. In other words, you're trying to pull the "first of list" from a list that doesn't exist. It's not clear to me what you're asking here, given the code doesn't run without error.

Comment: @alidesu Your code with the violations mentioned above removed: https://godbolt.org/z/zRK3bR You don't need `start` for anything.

Comment: If I want to be clear, i want to print from 11 to 99. What should i do ?
Is there a problem this "print()" function ?

Comment: You'll print from 91 back to 11 in decrements of 10 with the values you entered. Print the values as you enter them to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If that `for` cycle that inserts elements should really end with `i += 11`, then yes, `99` is the first element in the list.

2) The list looks like this `99 -> 88 -> ... -> 22 -> 11`. There is no way of getting from `11` to `22`, you can only traverse the list in one direction. That's a characteristic of the `list` data structure.

If you need to print the elements in the same order you insert them, you need to insert at the end on the list, not at the front. For that `head` is not enough, you'd need another pointer to the list, one pointing to the end, let's call it `tail`. `insert()` would then use `tail` in much the same way as it uses `head` now (it would not touch or change `head` at all ).

Comment: Thanks for your Wonderful answer :D

Comment: "*For that `head` is not enough*" it is if you're willing to iterate to the end of the list on every push_back. Or if you have an `insert_after()` that takes a `Node*`. By no means do you *need* a `tail`.